# python return list of sorted dictionary keys

Tags: python-3.x, list, key, ordereddictionary

I'm sure this has been asked and answered, but I cant find it.  I have this dictionary:

```
{'22775': 15.9, 
 '22778': 29.2, 
 '22776': 20.25, 
 '22773': 9.65, 
 '22777': 22.9, 
 '22774': 12.45}
```

a string and a float.

I want to list the key strings in a tk listbox to allow the user to select one and then use the corresponding float in a calculation to determine a delay factor in an event.

I have this code:

```
def dic_entry(line):
    #Create key:value pairs from string
    key, sep, value = line.strip().partition(":")
    return key, float(value)

with open(filename1) as f_obj:    
    s = dict(dic_entry(line) for line in f_obj)
print (s) #for testing only
s_ord = sorted(s.items(),key=lambda x: x[1])
print (s_ord)
```

The first print gets me

```
{'22775': 15.9, 
 '22778': 29.2, 
 '22776': 20.25, 
 '22773': 9.65, 
 '22777': 22.9, 
 '22774': 12.45}
```

as expected. The second, which I hoped would give me an ordered list of keys gets me

```
[('22773', 9.65), 
 ('22774', 12.45), 
 ('22775', 15.9), 
 ('22776', 20.25), 
 ('22777', 22.9), 
 ('22778', 29.2)].
```

I have tried using `sorteddictionary` from the collections module and it gives me a sorted dictionary, but I'm having trouble extracting a list of keys.

```
s_ord2 = []
for keys in s.items():  
  s_ord2.append (keys)
print (s_ord2)
```

gives me a list of key value pairs:

```
[('22776', 20.25), 
 ('22777', 22.9), 
 ('22774', 12.45), 
 ('22773', 9.65), 
 ('22778', 29.2), 
 ('22775', 15.9)]
```

I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: `sorted(s.items(),key=lambda x: x[1])` works fine for me to sort on the values.  This question is not very clear on what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `items` when you want to use `keys`:

```
In [1]: d = {'z': 3, 'b': 4, 'a': 9}

In [2]: sorted(d.keys())
Out[2]: ['a', 'b', 'z']

In [3]: sorted(d.items())
Out[3]: [('a', 9), ('b', 4), ('z', 3)]
```

`d.items()` gives you tuples of (key, value); `d.keys()` just gives you just the keys.

Comment: that's exactly what i need - thanks.  This was my first question (although I search frequently) and I appreciate the help.  I'm just learning the interface,  so I'm sorry for any formatting errors.

Comment: @TomFitzsimons Happy to help! And if the answer is useful, please accept it - that makes it more helpful to future searchers.

Comment: If that means hit the little green check mark - done!